# Saving html file in eclipse has no effect

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, dynamic, web

So I've created a Dynamic Web application with Tomcat in Eclipse and it worked fine yesterday. Now when I try making changes to a file and running it has no effect, it still runs the old version of the file as if I haven't changed anything (even if I leave the file blank and save).

Answer (score 0):

Just to start, do you automatic publishing turned on for your server.
If not try restarting the server after you save the file and see if it works.

Comment: How do I check if automatic publishing is turned on? Restarting the server didn't help.

Comment: are you sure..right click the server you have added, click on clean option and then right click and restart

Comment: I did as you said and nothing changed.

Comment: Can you browser to the file to wherever you eclipse workspace is and check for the date modified and try opening the file with notepad to see if it has your changes.

Comment: Trying opening in a different browser. Try on your phone via localhost:8080/ and see if it shows the old page

Comment: Opening in a different browser shows the updated page. I think the problem is with Eclipse.

Comment: I think then the issue is with the browser cache instead of eclipse, because if were to be an issue with Eclipse the page would have not been updated in a different browser as well.

Comment: But the browser is integrated in Eclipse, no?